# Ignore small changes from SensorEventListener ( Compass app )

Tags: java, android, compass, sensormanager

i'm creating a compass application for testing purposes and it works just fine and the arrow image points to the north pole but it changes too much and make very small moves right and left in milliseconds even if the device is not moving.

My question is how to ignore these small changes ? thank you

```
public class Compass implements SensorEventListener {
private static final String TAG = "Compass";

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor gsensor;
private Sensor msensor;
private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
private float azimuth = 0f;
private float currectAzimuth = 0;

// compass arrow to rotate
public ImageView arrowView = null;

public Compass(Context context) {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    gsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    msensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
}

public void start() {
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gsensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, msensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

public void stop() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

private void adjustArrow() {
    if (arrowView == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "arrow view is not set");
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "will set rotation from " + currectAzimuth + " to "
            + azimuth);

    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(-currectAzimuth, -azimuth,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    currectAzimuth = azimuth;

    an.setDuration(500);
    an.setRepeatCount(0);
    an.setFillAfter(true);

    arrowView.startAnimation(an);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    final float alpha = 0.97f;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];

            // mGravity = event.values;

            // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(mGravity[0]));
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            // mGeomagnetic = event.values;

            mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha)
                    * event.values[2];
            // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(event.values[0]));

        }

        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (rad): " + azimuth);
            azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
            azimuth = (azimuth + 360) % 360;
            // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (deg): " + azimuth);
            adjustArrow();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
```

Comment: If you can measure the small changes. Then you can set a minimum threshold value, if the change is greater than the threshold then only show it.

Comment: Keep a history and average the values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979238/android-getorientation-azimuth-gets-polluted-when-phone-is-tilted/17981374#17981374

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometer is very sensitive.

onSensorChanged is being fired for sensor type_accelerometer even on slightest movement.

Keep a check on event.values[0],  event.values[1] and  event.values[2] value (set a threshold above which compass will respond), which in essence are x,y and z co-ordinate acceleration vector values.

You can use a filter on accelerometer too.

This is a low cut filter:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
  float x = se.values[0];
  float y = se.values[1];
  float z = se.values[2];
  mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
  mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
  float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
  mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
}
```

and then:

```
if(mAccel>12||status)
  {
    //move compass : 
        float orientation[] = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
        // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (rad): " + azimuth); 
        azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
        azimuth = (azimuth + 360) % 360;
        // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (deg): " + azimuth); 
        adjustArrow(); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but what are mAccelLast, mAccelCurrent and mAccel?

Comment: mAccelCurrent--> x,y,z axis accelerometer readings mean diff     mAccelLast --> Last value of mAccelCurrent  mAccel --> is the filter value calculated based on previous values and can be used as minimum threshold above which something is fired like moving compass

Comment: That didn't work, please can you help me editing my code above with the changes you suggested ? i'll appreciate this very much

Comment: Probably because of line  boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic); which will always be true (unless device is in free fall)